# Scala : Write to a file inside foreachRDD

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I'm using Spark streaming to process data coming from Kafka. And I would like to write the result in a file (on local). When I print on console everything works fine and I get my results but when I try to write that to a file I get an error.

I use `PrintWriter` to do that, but I get this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.NotSerializableException: DStream checkpointing has been enabled but the DStreams with their functions are not serializable
java.io.PrintWriter
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: java.io.PrintWriter, value: java.io.PrintWriter@20f6f88c)
    - field (class: streaming.followProduction$$anonfun$main$1, name: qualityWriter$1, type: class java.io.PrintWriter)
    - object (class streaming.followProduction$$anonfun$main$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: streaming.followProduction$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, name: $outer, type: class streaming.followProduction$$anonfun$main$1)
    - object (class streaming.followProduction$$anonfun$main$1$$anonfun$apply$1, <function1>)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3, name: cleanedF$1, type: interface scala.Function1)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3, <function2>)
    - writeObject data (class: org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStreamCheckpointData)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream$DirectKafkaInputDStreamCheckpointData,
```

I guess I can't use the writer like this inside the ForeachRDD !

Here is my code :

```
object followProduction extends Serializable {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {

    val qualityWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("diskQuality.txt"))
    qualityWriter.append("dateTime , quality , status \n")

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://address:7077").setAppName("followProcess").set("spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "4")
    val sc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

    sc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "address:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> s"${UUID.randomUUID().toString}",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )

    val topics = Array("A", "C")

    topics.foreach(t => {

      val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
        sc,
        PreferConsistent,
        Subscribe[String, String](Array(t), kafkaParams)
      )

      stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {

        rdd.collect().foreach(i => {

          val record = i.value()
          val newCsvRecord = process(t, record)

          println(newCsvRecord)

          qualityWriter.append(newCsvRecord)

        })
      })

    })

    qualityWriter.close()

    sc.start()
    sc.awaitTermination()

  }

  var componentQuantity: componentQuantity = new componentQuantity("", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
  var diskQuality: diskQuality = new diskQuality("", 0.0)

  def process(topic: String, record: String): String = topic match {
    case "A" => componentQuantity.checkQuantity(record)
    case "C" => diskQuality.followQuality(record)
  }
}
```

I have this class I am calling :

```
case class diskQuality(datetime: String, quality: Double) extends Serializable {

  def followQuality(record: String): String = {

    val dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")


    var recQuality = msgParse(record).quality
    var date: Date = dateFormat.parse(msgParse(record).datetime)
    var recDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss").format(date)

    // some operations here

    return recDateTime + " , " + recQuality

  }

  def msgParse(value: String): diskQuality = {

    import org.json4s._
    import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

    implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

    val res = parse(value).extract[diskQuality]
    return res

  }
}
```

How can I achieve this ? I'm new to both Spark and Scala so maybe I'm not doing things right. 
Thank you for your time

**EDIT :**

I've changed My code and I don't get this error anymore. But at the same time, I have only the first line in my file and the records are not appended. The writer (handleWriter) inside is actually not working.

Here is my code :

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {

    val qualityWriter = new PrintWriter(file)
    qualityWriter.write("dateTime , quality , status \n")
    qualityWriter.close()

    rdd.collect().foreach(i =>
    {
      val record = i.value()

      val newCsvRecord = process(topic , record)

      val handleWriter = new PrintWriter(file)
      handleWriter.append(newCsvRecord)
      handleWriter.close()

      println(newCsvRecord)
    })
  })
```

Where did I miss ? Maybe I'm doing this wrong ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PrintWriter` is a local resource, bound to a single machine and cannot be serialized.

To remove this object from the Java serialization plan, we can declare it `@transient`. That means that a serialization form of the `followProduction` object will not attempt to serialize this field.

In the code of the question, it should be declared as:

```
@transient val qualityWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("diskQuality.txt"))
```

Then it becomes possible to use it within the `foreachRDD` closure.

But, this process does not solve issues that have to do with the proper handling of the file. The `qualityWriter.close()` will be executed on the first pass of the streaming job and the file descriptor will be closed for writing during the execution of the job. To properly use local resources, such as a `File`, I would follow Yuval suggestion to recreate the PrintWriter within the `foreachRDD` closure. The missing piece is declaring the new `PrintWritter` in append mode. The modified code within the `foreachRDD` will look like this (making some additional code changes):

```
// Initialization phase

val qualityWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("diskQuality.txt"))
qualityWriter.println("dateTime , quality , status")
qualityWriter.close()

....

dstream.foreachRDD{ rdd => 

  val data = rdd.map(e => e.value())
                .collect() // get the data locally
                .map(i=> process(topic , i))  // create csv records
  val allRecords = data.mkString("\n") // why do I/O if we can do in-mem?     
  val handleWriter = new PrintWriter(file, append=true)
  handleWriter.append(allRecords)
  handleWriter.close()

}
```

---

Few notes about the code in the question:

> "spark.streaming.concurrentJobs", "4"

This will create an issue with multiple threads writing to the same local file. It's probably also being misused in this context.

> sc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

There seems to be no need for checkpointing on this job.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing to do would be to create the instance of `PrintWriter` inside `foreachRDD`, which means it wouldn't be captured by the function closure:

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd => {
  val qualityWriter = new PrintWriter(new File("diskQuality.txt"))
  qualityWriter.append("dateTime , quality , status \n")  

  rdd.collect().foreach(i => {
    val record = i.value()
    val newCsvRecord = process(t, record)
    qualityWriter.append(newCsvRecord)
    })
  })
})
```